# Python hacking around read only property

Tags: python

I am using some third party code that has some read only properties.
I obviously want to alter them regardless.

I tried using `del` but I keep getting: `AttributeError: can't delete attribute`

Here is my code:

```
for page in suggested_pages:
    url = page.url + '?source=smart_404'
    full_url = page.full_url + '?source=smart_404'

    del page.url
    del page.full_url

    page.url = url
    page.full_url = full_url
```

**Edit people have been asking for the code of the properties**

```
@property
def full_url(self):
    """Return the full URL (including protocol / domain) to this page, or None if it is not routable"""
    url_parts = self.get_url_parts()

    if url_parts is None:
        # page is not routable
        return

    site_id, root_url, page_path = url_parts

    return root_url + page_path

@property
def url(self):
    """
    Return the 'most appropriate' URL for referring to this page from the pages we serve,
    within the Wagtail backend and actual website templates;
    this is the local URL (starting with '/') if we're only running a single site
    (i.e. we know that whatever the current page is being served from, this link will be on the
    same domain), and the full URL (with domain) if not.
    Return None if the page is not routable.
    """
    url_parts = self.get_url_parts()

    if url_parts is None:
        # page is not routable
        return

    site_id, root_url, page_path = url_parts

    if len(Site.get_site_root_paths()) == 1:
        # we're only running a single site, so a local URL is sufficient
        return page_path
    else:
        return root_url + page_path
```

The code came from [Wagtail CMS](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L789)

Comment: Why do you try to del them first? Why not just assign page.url directly?

Comment: I get this `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: You're going to need to show the code of whatever class `page` is.

Comment: Obviously there is no setter for `url`, why are you trying to override that behavior?

Comment: @selcuk because I want to alter the url...

Comment: I understand that, but the 3rd party library is obviously not meant to be used like that. You can possibly fork it and create your own version.

Comment: So your code shows that `url` is calculated dynamically. What would it even mean to "set" it?

Comment: I thought that with a dynamic language anything was possible, never mind what the library creator intended?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, so instead of getting the url, I want the url plus a query string.

Comment: @L3viathan https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L789

Comment: The page class has a `self.url_path` which you can probably alter. Altering it will probably break something. Just because you can change things doesn't mean that changing them does what you want.

Comment: The main point is that `url` isn't really a property. It's actually a method, but they've defined a getter so that it can be accessed like a property.

Comment: @Barmar but is there anyway i can wipe it off the class definition dynamically, and replace it with my own implementation like my first code snippet?

Comment: @Lee Can you tell us why you want to change the url? Do you want a side to appear under a specific url?

Comment: @syntonym i want to use a query string for metrics collection. This code is part of a library that is itself used in other applications, so i just want to update the urls with no work on the "client" apps

Comment: @Lee So you have an application with wagtail and you want to dynamically change the url of an endpoint? How does the query string play into that?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, read only properties are generally implemented through the `property` function.

Example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val
```

That means that the read only property is not an attribute of the object, but a special attribute of the class itself.

Hopefully, you can easily add a setter to a property:

```
def setval(self, val):
    self._val = val
A.val = A.val.setter(setval)
a = A(5)
a.val
-> 5
a.val = 6
-> 6
```

Or you can also completely replace the property. For your classes, you could do (I use clazz for the name of the class you want to change)

```
clazz.orig_url = url
def set_url(self, url):
    self._url = url
clazz.url = property((lambda self: self._url), seturl)
```

You can then do:

```
page.url = url
print(page.url)
```

The main caveat is that you have to modify the owning class and not only the instance.